# How long will I receive the conferred letter after my phd thesis's corrections have been accepted by examiners?

Tags: phd, thesis, united-kingdom

I'm a UK phd student. I've heard from my supervisor that examiners have accepted the corrections of my phd thesis, which is really a piece of good news but still can't release my panic, because I need to get the conferred letter ASAP to prove to my employer. The deadline is mid-August.

I'd like to know how long after my phd thesis's corrections have been accepted by examiners I'll receive the conferred letter.

Comment: Seems like something to ask your advisor, letting them know your deadline in case something special needs to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this depends entirely on the university and inside the university on the speed with which messages are exchanged. You need to ask them instead of us. It might also be possible to negotiate with your employer who might be willing to accept a letter from your Ph.D. advisor as an interim solution.